# How to fix navbar not showing sticky with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap 4. I want to make the navbar sticky with the help of jquery. So I added a condition if the scroll greater than or equal to 50 I want to add the sticky navbar class else remove the navbar sticky class. I've used something similar in my other projects. but it's not working in this one. any idea why? thanks :)

**Bootstrap & JS**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-custom sticky sticky-dark navbar-light">

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scroll >= 50) {
            $(".sticky").addClass("nav-sticky");
        } else {
            $(".sticky").removeClass("nav-sticky");
        }
    });
```

**CSS**

```
.nav-item .nav-link {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #343a40;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar-custom {
  padding: 14px 0px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 0px;
  z-index: 999;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-custom .logo .logo-dark {
  display: none;
}

.navbar-custom .logo .ligo-light {
  display: inline-block;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-nav li a {
  line-height: 26px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  background-color: transparent !important;
  padding: 6px 0;
  margin: 0 20px;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-nav li .nav-link {
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-nav li.active a, .navbar-custom .navbar-nav li a:hover, .navbar-custom .navbar-nav li a:active {
  color: #fff !important;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-toggles {
  padding: .25rem .75rem;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: 0 0;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  color: #fff;
  outline: 0;
}

.navbar-toggler {
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  color: #fff;
}

.nav .open > a,
.nav .open > a:focus,
.nav .open > a:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: #5e62ff;
}

.menu-toggle {
  padding: 4.5px 10px !important;
}

.menu-toggle span {
  line-height: 27px;
}

/*----- Navbar Sticky -----*/

.nav-sticky.navbar-custom {
  margin-top: 0px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
          box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
  color: #000000 !important;
}

.nav-sticky.navbar-custom .navbar-toggles {
  padding: .25rem .75rem;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  outline: 0;
}

.nav-sticky.navbar-custom .navbar-nav {
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.nav-sticky.navbar-custom .navbar-nav li a {
  color: #8a8aa0 !important;
}

.nav-sticky.navbar-custom .navbar-nav li.active a, .nav-sticky.navbar-custom .navbar-nav li a:hover, .nav-sticky.navbar-custom .navbar-nav li a:active {
  color: #5e62ff !important;
}

.nav-sticky .logo .logo-dark {
  display: inline-block !important;
}

.nav-sticky .logo .logo-light {
  display: none !important;
}

.navbar-toggler:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav li a {
  color: #8a8aa0 !important;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav li.active a, .navbar-light .navbar-nav li a:hover, .navbar-light .navbar-nav li a:active {
  color: #5e62ff !important;
}

@media (min-width: 200px) and (max-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-custom {
    margin-top: 0px;
    background-color: #ffffff !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
            box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
    color: #ffffff !important;
  }
  .navbar-custom .navbar-nav {
    margin-top: 0px;
  }
  .navbar-custom .navbar-nav li a {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
    transition: all 0.4s;
    color: #9b9bae !important;
    margin: 0px;
  }
  .navbar-custom .navbar-nav li.active a {
    border-color: transparent;
  }
  .navbar-custom .navbar-nav li.active a, .navbar-custom .navbar-nav li a:hover, .navbar-custom .navbar-nav li a:active {
    color: #5e62ff !important;
  }
  .navbar-custom > .container {
    width: 90%;
  }
  .navbar-custom .logo .logo-dark {
    display: inline-block !important;
  }
  .navbar-custom .logo .logo-light {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .navbar-custom.navbar-light .navbar-nav li.active a, .navbar-custom.navbar-light .navbar-nav li a:hover, .navbar-custom.navbar-light .navbar-nav li a:active {
    color: #343a40 !important;
  }
  .navbar-toggler {
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    color: #343a40;
  }
  .navbar-collapse {
    padding: 0 20px;
  }
  .navbar-light .nav-item .nav-link:after {
    background: #343a40;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .nav-dark .navbar-nav li a {
    color: #9090a5 !important;
  }
  .nav-dark .navbar-nav li.active a, .nav-dark .navbar-nav li a:hover, .nav-dark .navbar-nav li a:active {
    color: #5e62ff !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you include the css classes?

Comment: Please put your code in snippet or JS fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

First, start debugging to find out where the issue is coming from.
Use the below code and see whether the alert box is showing correctly. So that you find out which part of your code is not working.

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-custom sticky sticky-dark navbar-light">

  <script>

 $(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {

        var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
        console.log($('.nav').data('hola'))
        if (scroll >= 50) {
            $("nav").addClass("nav-sticky");
        } else {
            $("nav").removeClass("nav-sticky");
        }
    });

});
        </script>
```

This one is working. Check the JS Fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/rajeevRF/63n8xfz9/15/)

Comment: Not sure who did.

Comment: no alert box showing? Change the code as per my updated answer.

Comment: Nope, still not. it looks like the condition is not working

Comment: Actually this is not an answer, this a way to debug the problem

Comment: Your JSFiddle wasn't working for me, I updated it a bit
https://jsfiddle.net/45nzk0te/

Comment: It seems like he has updated his question with CSS. Yes it is working for me now. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use `navbar-fixed-top` class instead of `nav-sticky` in your code as like below.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
            var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (scroll >= 50) {
                $(".sticky").addClass("navbar-fixed-top");
            } else {
                $(".sticky").removeClass("navbar-fixed-top");
            }
        });
```

It will work.

Comment: Please mark it as answer, if this code works for you.